# Download a textfile with dropbox core api and android

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

i have a problem with download a textfile. I have no file contents after the dowload, the downloaded file is empty. Android and Core Api

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        File fileDown = new File(LOCAL_PATH_DOWNLOAD);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDown);//
        DropboxAPI.DropboxFileInfo info = mApi.getFile(DROPBOX_FILE_DIR_DOWNLOAD, null, outputStream, null);

        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong: " + e);
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What do i wrong? Thanks for help

Comment: Cross-linking with https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203833533-Download-textfile on the Dropbox API forum.

Comment: Do you get any output or errors? Are you sure the file on Dropbox isn't itself empty?

Comment: I have an output. presumably the file who was created for the outpurstream. The file in dropbox has definitly a content. A string per line for a total of five lines

Answer (score 0):

i use above code to do this

```
File file= new File("/sdcard/New_csv_file.csv");
  OutputStream out= null;
  boolean result=false;
  try {
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
           DropboxFileInfo info = mApi.getFile("/photos/New_csv_file.csv", null, out, null);
           Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The file's rev is: " + info.getMetadata().rev);
           Intent JumpToParseCSV=new Intent(context,ParseCSV.class);
            JumpToParseCSV.putExtra("FileName", file.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.i("path", "FileName"+ file.getAbsolutePath());
             ((Activity) context).finish();
            context.startActivity(JumpToParseCSV);
            result=true;
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
           Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while downloading.");
           file.delete();
           result=false;
        }


return result;
```

Comment: It works not, my textfile is empty. What do you do with Intent Jump... context.startActivity ? It is not for download the file, but for show the file in an activity, right?